# bootstrap carousel / responsive menu

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

[image]

On my web page there is a responsive drop-down menu (3 lines) and Bootstrap carousel. On mobile, when the image slides, it seems like the menu, those three lines, are sliding too. Has anyone any idea why is that happening?

Here is the menu

```
<div class="row row-menu fixed-nav"> 
     <div class="container">
         <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 logo">
              <a href="index.php" class="pull-left logo"><img src="images/crow_logo_152x51.png" alt=""></a>

               <div class="mainmenu-showmenu-button pull-right">
                   <a onclick="$('.mainmenu li.active').has('.flyout').toggleClass('active').find('flyout').toggle(0);$('.mainmenu').slideToggle(100);" href="Javascript:return void(0);">
                      <div class="lines">
                           <span></span>
                           <span></span>
                           <span></span>
                      </div>

                   </a>
               </div> <!--/.mainmenu-showmenu-button-->

           </div>

           <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-mainmenu">
              <ul class="mainmenu">    
                  <li>
                      <a href="about.php" title="About" class="menufont">Despre</a>

                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <a href="<?=$lang;?>/service/services.html" title="Software and services" class="mainmenulink menufont menu">    
                           <span class="text">Servicii & Soluții</span>
                           <span class="arrow"></span>
                       </a>
                       <div class="flyout container" style="display:none;">
                           <div class="submenu">
                               <ul class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                  <li class="submenutitle">Business</li>                 
                                  <li>
                                      <a href="consult.php" title="Accounting">Consultanță IT</a>
                                  </li> 
                                  <li>
                                      <a href="management.php" title="Payroll and HRM">Managementul Relațiilor cu Clienții</a>
                                  </li> 
                                  <li><a href="enterprise.php" title="Invoicing">Enterprise Content Management</a></li> 
                                  <li><a href="business.php" title="Debt collection">Business Intelligence</a></li> 
                                  <li><a href="integration.php" title="CRM">Integrarea Aplicațiilor Întreprinderii</a></li> 
                                  <li><a href="enterprise-resource.php" title="Procurement">Enterprise Resource Planning</a></li>    
                                  <li><a href="cloud.php" title="Procurement">Cloud Computing</a></li>
                              <!-- <li><a href="<?=$lang;?>/service/services.html" title="Procurement">Servicii</a></li>  -->         
                             </ul> 

                           </div>
                     </div>
                  </li>
                 <li>
                     <a href="cariera.php" title="Careers" class="menufont">Carieră</a>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                      <a href="press-center.php" title="Press Center" class="menufont">Centru de Presă</a>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                     <a href="contact.php" title="Contacte" class="menufont">Contacte</a>
                 </li>

            </ul>
        </div>

  </div> <!--/.row row-menu-->
```

And this is the carousel

```
<div class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" id="carousel-block">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item slide active" style="background-image: url('images/slideshow/business.jpg')">
            <article class="carouselarticle">
                <div class="carouseltxt overlay bg-blue txt-white cta-white">
                    <header>
                        <h3 class="bg-blue text-small">Soluții și servicii pentru afacerea dumneavoastră</h3>
                    </header>
                    <span>
                        <p>EnCrow vă poate ajuta în găsirea celor mai bune soluții pentru companie</p>
                    </span>

                    <a href="service-business.php" class="cta" title="See our accounting solutions" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'StartPage_CTA_See our accounting solutions', 'accounting software and services']);" target="_top">
                        <p class="p8">Soluțiile și Serviciile Noastre Business</p>
                    </a>
                </div> 
            </article>
        </div> <!--/.item-->

        <div class="item slide" style="background-image: url('images/slideshow/sectoare.jpg')"> 
            <article class="carouselarticle">
                <div class="carouseltxt overlay bg-pink">
                    <header>
                        <h3 id="header_nr2" class="text-medium">Soluții și aplicații pentru industrii</h3>
                    </header>
                    <span>
                        <p>Soluțiile noastre pentru industrii vor satisface așteptările clienților dumneavoastră</p>
                    </span>

                    <a href="services-sectoare.php" class="cta" title="Payroll" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'StartPage_CTA_Payroll', 'Payroll front page']);" target="_top">
                        <p class="p8">Soluții și Aplicații pentru Industrii</p>
                    </a>
                </div> 
            </article>
        </div> <!--/.item-->

        <div class="item slide" style="background-image: url('images/slideshow/web.jpg')">    
            <article class="carouselarticle">
                <div class="carouseltxt overlay bg-orange txt-white cta-white">
                    <header>
                        <h3 id="header_nr3" class="text-medium">Dezvoltare web și soluții web-orientate</h3>
                    </header>
                    <span>
                        <p>Experiența noastră asigură realizarea calitativă a proiectelor</p>
                    </span>

                    <a href="dezvoltare-web.php" class="cta" title="Retail" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'StartPage_CTA_Retail', 'Retail IT solutions']);" target="_top">
                        <p class="p8">Dezvoltare și Soluții Web  </p>
                    </a>
                </div> 
            </article>
        </div> <!--/.item-->

        <div class="item slide" style="background-image: url('images/slideshow/mobil.jpg')">    
            <article class="carouselarticle">
                <div class="carouseltxt overlay bg-violet">
                    <header>
                        <h3 id="header_nr4" class="text-medium">Dezvoltare de aplicații și soluții mobile</h3>
                    </header>
                    <span>
                        <p>Dezvoltăm aplicații mobile de care ai nevoie la cele mai înalte standarde</p>
                    </span>

                    <a href="dezvoltare-mobila.php" class="cta" title="Retail" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'StartPage_CTA_Retail', 'Retail IT solutions']);" target="_top">
                        <p class="p8">Aplicații și Soluții Mobile</p>
                    </a>
                </div> 
            </article>
        </div>

    </div> <!--/.carousel-inner-->

</div> <!--/.carousel slide-->
<div class="container startpage-flex-control">
    <ul class="nav  startpage-flex-control-nav" id="carousel-block-buttons">
        <li class="active" data-target="#carousel-block" data-slide-to="0">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#"><span>Business</span></a>
        </li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-block" data-slide-to="1">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#"><span>Sectoare</span></a>
        </li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-block" data-slide-to="2">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#"><span>Dezvoltare Web</span></a>
        </li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-block" data-slide-to="3">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#"><span>Dezvoltare Mobila</span></a>
        </li> 
    </ul> <!--/.nav nav-justified-->
</div>
```

Comment: :) how can we verify without any line of code?

Comment: You are missing a closing `</div>` tag for the main menu. Add it and it should be ok

Comment: still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you have place navbar inside the carousel. 
please separate them.
eg.

```
<nav>
 ... yuor nav code
</nav>

<div class="carousel">
  ... your carousel code
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing `</div>` tag for the main menu:

```
<div class="row row-menu fixed-nav"> 
   <div class="container">
     <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 logo">
          <a href="index.php" class="pull-left logo"><img src="images/crow_logo_152x51.png" alt=""></a>

           <div class="mainmenu-showmenu-button pull-right">
               <a onclick="$('.mainmenu li.active').has('.flyout').toggleClass('active').find('flyout').toggle(0);$('.mainmenu').slideToggle(100);" href="Javascript:return void(0);">
                  <div class="lines">
                       <span></span>
                       <span></span>
                       <span></span>
                  </div>

               </a>
           </div> <!--/.mainmenu-showmenu-button-->

       </div>

       <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-mainmenu">
          <ul class="mainmenu">    
              <li>
                  <a href="about.php" title="About" class="menufont">Despre</a>

               </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="<?=$lang;?>/service/services.html" title="Software and services" class="mainmenulink menufont menu">    
                       <span class="text">Servicii & Soluții</span>
                       <span class="arrow"></span>
                   </a>
                   <div class="flyout container" style="display:none;">
                       <div class="submenu">
                           <ul class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                              <li class="submenutitle">Business</li>                 
                              <li>
                                  <a href="consult.php" title="Accounting">Consultanță IT</a>
                              </li> 
                              <li>
                                  <a href="management.php" title="Payroll and HRM">Managementul Relațiilor cu Clienții</a>
                              </li> 
                              <li><a href="enterprise.php" title="Invoicing">Enterprise Content Management</a></li> 
                              <li><a href="business.php" title="Debt collection">Business Intelligence</a></li> 
                              <li><a href="integration.php" title="CRM">Integrarea Aplicațiilor Întreprinderii</a></li> 
                              <li><a href="enterprise-resource.php" title="Procurement">Enterprise Resource Planning</a></li>    
                              <li><a href="cloud.php" title="Procurement">Cloud Computing</a></li>
                          <!-- <li><a href="<?=$lang;?>/service/services.html" title="Procurement">Servicii</a></li>  -->         
                         </ul> 

                       </div>
                 </div>
              </li>
             <li>
                 <a href="cariera.php" title="Careers" class="menufont">Carieră</a>
             </li>
             <li>
                  <a href="press-center.php" title="Press Center" class="menufont">Centru de Presă</a>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <a href="contact.php" title="Contacte" class="menufont">Contacte</a>
             </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> <!--/.row row-menu-->
```